# Flutter OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13

Tags: flutter, dart, android-external-storage

I've created an app that download a encrypted file from google drive and stores it on the device downloads folder. Then it decrypts(using the aes_crypt_null_safe package) that file and stores it as a plain text file. Below are the two functions.

**To Download from drive**

```
Future<void> downloadFromDrive(String fName, String gdID) async {
var client = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
var ga = drive.DriveApi(client);
drive.Media file = await ga.files
    .get(gdID, downloadOptions: drive.DownloadOptions.fullMedia) as Media;
print(file.stream);

final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
print(directory?.path);
final saveFile =
    File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/test_gdrive_download.txt.aes');
List<int> dataStore = [];
file.stream.listen((data) {
  print("DataReceived: ${data.length}");
  dataStore.insertAll(dataStore.length, data);
}, onDone: () async {
  print("Task Done");
  await saveFile.writeAsBytes(dataStore);
  print("File saved at ${saveFile.path}");
}, onError: (error) {
  print("Some Error");
});
await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
});
}
```

**To Decrypt**

```
decryptJsonFile({required String srcPath, required String destPath}) async {
crypt.decryptFileSync(srcPath, destPath);
}
```

**calling the two functions**

```
   onPressed: () async {
                print("Downloading file from drive...");
                await downloadFromDrive("ideas", fileId.toString());
                print("Decrypting the file downloaded from drive...");
                await decryptJsonFile(
                    srcPath: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/test_gdrive_download.txt.aes',
                    destPath: '/storage/emulated/0/Download/decrypted_file.txt');
              },
```

when I try to trigger these functions,It downloads the file perfectly and stores it on the downloads folder but when I try to decrypt is I get the below error,

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Failed to open /storage/emulated/0/Download/test_gdrive_download.txt.aes for writing., path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/decrypted_file.txt' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)
```

I've provided all the required permissions in my android manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

and

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: you need to ask storage access permission from user to allow access to storage read and write

Answer (score 0):

add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This is a high-risk permission and should only be used if really necessary.
If the application is published on the Store, you must submit a justification.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955